# RichTextBox C# Draw Text method?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Whats the method that draws the text in a richTextBox ?
I tried overriding OnRender() but this is only called when I initialize richTextBox not when I'm typing. I dont want to call OnSelectionChange Or OnTextChange.
I need the method that draws the text.

Im using this [RichtextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) the Windows.Controls

**EDIT**

My RichTextBox contains words separated by image separators. I want to Use the OnDraw method or any to create a rectangle to add an adorner image on top of each word.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you'd like to override the text drawing method?

Comment: @MattS Calculate the rectangle for each word to add an adorner layer, I got null on textChange because the words are not drawn yet and their position is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a method that draws text.  WPF RichTextBox holds FlowDocuments, which are closely related to XPS.  They are rendered in the same way WPF is.

**Edit:** Use the methods described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SmartTextBox.aspx) to get the position of text and add adorners.

**Edit 2:** Use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306679/wpf-richtextbox-question) to get character positions.

```
Rect rect = base.GetRectFromCharacterIndex( idx );
```

Comment: so theres no way i can override or create a method that draws the text for me ?

Comment: Correct. You have to change the FlowDocument, just as in WPF you must change the Xaml and cannot override some text drawing function.  I realize there is an OnRender, but this is only for free hand drawing in a DrawingVisual type control, and doesn't work with Xaml.

Comment: do u suggest any solution for that? I need to use WPF RTB in my program.

Comment: You'd have to add more to your question about what you're putting in the RTB, where you are getting it, how you want to change the text, etc.

Comment: This uses SmartTextBox not RichTextBox.

Comment: @AresAvatar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1677/discussion-between-raym0nd-and-aresavatar)